# How to modify a nixos package configuration

Tags: git, nixos, nix

I am building a nixos system in a network that is only able to access the outside world through a web proxy. The [nixos grub configuration](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/e91d788b7cfba93b67a516eff22379abdc08eb41/pkgs/tools/misc/grub/2.0x.nix#L45) tries to access the grub repository through a `git://` URL which obviously does not work at my network.

Therefore I want to replace the `git://` url by the corresponding `http://` URL. (savannah supports [both](http://savannah.gnu.org/maintenance/UsingGit/).) The corresponding [nix documentation](https://nixos.org/wiki/Nix_Modifying_Packages#Creating_a_config.nix_File) shows how to do it.

I created a file `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix` containing the following content:

```
{
  packageOverrides = pkgs: rec {
    grub = pkgs.grub.override {
      src.url="http://git.savannah.gnu.org/grub.git";
    };
  };
}
```

Unfortunately `nixos-rebuild switch` still tries to use the old URL.
What did I do wrong?

---

I also read the [customising packages](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/sec-package-management.html#sec-customising-packages) of the documentation.
From that it seems like I could add the following to `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:

```
nixpkgs.config.packageOverrides = pkgs: {
    grub = pkgs.grub.overrideDerivation (pkgs.grub ( attrs: {
        url = "http://git.savannah.gnu.org/grub.git";
        rev = "2ae9457e6eb4c352051fb32bc6fc931a22528ab2";
        sha256 = "1ik60qgkymg0xdns5az1hbxasspah2vzxg334rpbk2yy3h3nx5ln";
    }));
};
```

However `nixos-rebuild switchnixos-rebuild switch` still uses the old url. I probably need to add fetchurl, but I have no idea how to make this available at this place.

Answer (score 2):

`pkgs.grub.override` can override function at the top of the file. To override derivation parameters use `overrideDerivation` as described in http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/sec-package-management.html#sec-customising-packages

```
{
  packageOverrides = pkgs: rec {
    grub = pkgs.grub.override (attrs: {
      src = fetchurl { url = "http://git.savannah.gnu.org/grub.git";
                       sha256 = "";
      };
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: Putting exactly that code into `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix` did not change anything. `nixos-rebuild switch` still tries to fetch the old url.

Comment: Please read whole section at http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/sec-package-management.html#sec-customising-packages

Comment: Yes, I read the whole section, but I'm not sure if I understood it correctly. I added my other try to the question.

Comment: Try grub2 instead of grub.